# Plot with different errorbar styles in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot experimental data with two error bars (statistics, and statistics+systematics) which can be done like this:

```
unset key
set xrange [0.5:5.5]
$data << EOD
1 1 0.1 0.2
2 2 0.1 0.3
3 3 0.1 0.4
4 4 0.1 0.5
5 5 0.1 0.6
EOD
plot "$data" u 1:2:3 lc 1 ps 1 with yerrorbars, \
     "" u 1:2:4 lc 1 ps -1 with yerrorbars
```

However, this will add small horizontal lines to both error bars. I would like to have only a vertical line for the total error, and small horizontal lines for the statistical error only. I can remove all small horizontal lines by adding

```
set errorbars small
```

But how can I have visible horizontal lines ("`set errorbars large`") for the first plot command, and no horizontal lines ("`set errorbars small`") for the second plot command, but all in the same plot?

The result should look like this:
[image]

Comment: you could do a multiplot and overlay both plots (with different settings)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the plot without the horizontal lines, use `with vectors` instead of `with yerrorbars`:

```
unset key
set xrange [0.5:5.5]
$data << EOD
1 1 0.1 0.2
2 2 0.1 0.3
3 3 0.1 0.4
4 4 0.1 0.5
5 5 0.1 0.6
EOD
plot "$data" u 1:2:3 lc 1 ps 1 with yerrorbars, \
     "" u 1:($2-$4):(0):(2*$4) with vectors nohead lc 1
```

[image]